# How do I check if a string contains keywords?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that asks the user to enter keywords, and an essay, and then checks how many keywords were used in the essay.

Current output:

---

Enter keywords:

dog, cat

Enter essay:

i like cat

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException

---

Desired output:

---

Enter keywords:

dog, cat

Enter essay:

i like cat

1

---

Here's my code so far:

```
static int keywordsChecker(String shortEssay, String keywords) {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length(); i++) {

            String[] ary = keywords.split(",");

            if (shortEssay.contains(ary)) {
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);


        }
         return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter keywords: ");
        String keyword = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter essay: ");
        String essay = input.nextLine();
        keywordsChecker(essay, keyword);

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: iterate the keyword array and do the `contains` check with each entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
static int keywordsChecker(String shortEssay, String keywords) {
    int count = 0;
    String[] ary = keywords.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {            

        if (shortEssay.contains(ary[i])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter keywords: ");
    String keyword = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter essay: ");
    String essay = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(keywordsChecker(essay, keyword));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be your approach:

1. Split the keywords using `keywords.split(",");`.
2. Loop through the keywords array obtained in step #1.
3. check if each value from the array is available in `shortEssay` string or not using `shortEssay.contains(ary[index])`.

   1. If it's available, then increment the `count` variable by 1.
   2. else `continue` the loop.
4. Print and/or return the `count` variable.

---

And so your `keywordsChecker` method looks like this:

```
static int keywordsChecker(String shortEssay, String keywords) {
    int count = 0;
    String[] ary = keywords.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if (shortEssay.contains(ary[i])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);    
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer with explanation.

Comment: It displays an error at i < ary.length(), and tells me 'cannot find symbol' for the 'method length'

Comment: @user7329039 `str.length()` method can be used when using against a String. In our example, we're using an array so use `ary.length` property instead.

Comment: Better to use a for each loop, and avoid the need to call `length` (explicitly) in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
static int keywordsChecker(String shortEssay, String keywords)
{
    int count = 0;
    String[] ary = keywords.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if (shortEssay.contains(ary[i])) {
              count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Just you need to call this method and get your Keywords count. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static int keywordsChecker(String shortEssay, String keywords) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String keyword : keywords.split(",")) {
        if (shortEssay.contains(keyword.trim()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now when you call the method, you need to print the return value:

```
int count = keywordsChecker(essay, keyword);
System.out.println(count);
```